# Is it possible to create a guild invite link once a bot joins said guild?

Tags: discord.js

Alright, so basically I just want to know if it's possible to do what I said in the title. If so, could somebody tell me? It'd be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: >discord api doesn't allow this for bot accounts 
@GillesHeinesch It acutally does, your link even states `This is only available when using a __bot account.__`

Comment: You‘re right! Sorry for this! @PLASMAchicken

Comment: erm, could anyone tell me of where to find that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discord.js docs can be found [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome).

```js
client.on('guildCreate', guild => {
  if (!guild.me.hasPermission('CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE')) return console.log('Insufficient permission.');

  guild.channels.first().createInvite()
  .then(invite => console.log(invite.url))
  .catch(err => console.error());
});
```